# VBA using countifs error and dynamic ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, countif

I have the following set of mock-data in A4:B27, with row 4 holding the headers..

```
4. Entity Country
5. 12   countryb
6. 13   dave
7. 14   dan
8. 15   john
9. 16   james
10. 17  josh
11. 18  george
12. 19  geni
13. 20  gina
14. 10  countrya
15. 10  countrya
16. 11  country
17. 12  countryb
18. 12  countryb
19. 13  brian
20. 14  ryan
21. 15  louis
22. 16  tom
23. 17  chris
24. 18  mad
25. 19  barb
26. 20  james
27. 10  countrya
```

In VBA I want to ensure there are no duplicate entity-country combinations. This would be easily seen in a worksheet with the formula "=COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$27,A5,$B$5:$B$27,B5)". If the returned value is greater than one, I would want to highlight the entity-country cells to show a duplicate. In the above example rows  5, 14, 15, 17, 18, and 27 would be highlighted.

However after trying to create the VBA I'm stuck..

```
Sub test()

Dim cSheet As Worksheet
Set cSheet = Sheets("CL.AL1")

Dim trolSheet As Worksheet
Set trolSheet = Sheets("Control Sheet")

Dim currentRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer, currentColumn As Long
Dim listA As range, listB As range, cellA As String, cellB As String

cSheet.Select

currentColumn = 1
currentRow = 5
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set listA = range(Col_Letter(currentColumn) & currentRow & ":" & Col_Letter(currentColumn + 1) & lastRow)
Set listB = range(Col_Letter(currentColumn + 1) & currentRow & ":" & Col_Letter(currentColumn + 1) & lastRow)


Do While range("A" & currentRow) <> ""

cellA = (cSheet.range(Col_Letter(currentColumn) & currentRow).Value)
cellB = (cSheet.range(Col_Letter(currentColumn + 1) & currentRow).Value)

If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(listA, cellA, listB, cellB) > 1 Then
        Union(range(Col_Letter(currentColumn) & currentRow), _
            range(Col_Letter(currentColumn + 1) & currentRow)).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 49407
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
End If

If currentRow = lastRow Then
    currentRow = 5
    currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
    If currentColumn = 3 Then
    Exit Do
    End If
Else
currentRow = currentRow + 1
End If

Loop

Debug.Print (range(Col_Letter(currentColumn) & currentRow).Value)
Debug.Print (range(Col_Letter(currentColumn + 1) & currentRow).Value)

End Sub

Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

After executing the current VBA I receive a runtime 1004 error "unable to get the countifs property of the worksheet function class".

So. Can anyone help correct this error OR offer an alternative solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can do this with a formula and conditional formatting.

Comment: Conditional formatting will work - that is a much easier solution. But do you know why the countif worksheet function works and the countIFS does not?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the problem. Have you tried fully qualifying `Application.WorksheetFunction.......`?

Comment: Ah.. fully qualifying appears to have been the problem. Thanks a ton.

Comment: No problem. I've scratched my head a long time on that one before as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in as the formula for conditional formatting on cell A4 and then copy the formatting to the remainder of the column.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$4:$B$27,A4)>1
```